# Passing argument in cakephp

Tags: php, search, cakephp

I have to pass arguments in url after clicking on the search button.
for eg. my search action is **reports** but when i select a radio button it send like **reports/1** or **reports/2** etc.

Right now I am trying to do something like this.

```
echo $form->create('competitors', array('url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'reports'), $this->params['pass'])));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is wrong with that? it should work. you can also add $this->Form->hidden(...) to pass it in the form.